# How did Mlechha (foreigners) people come into existence?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, mahabharata

People of four castes that is found in India were born from mouth , shoulders , thighs and leg of Brahma.

How mlechhas (foreginers) came into existence ?

Do Vedas or any other Hindu texts specify them with any caste or varna ? Which varna or caste do they belong to ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: They sprung from Vasishta's divine cow Nandini. They were created to beat Vishwamitra's army

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks  , It gave a good idea. 
Would like to know any other place where it is written about them , maybe in more detailed way .